# Detecting host name in java

Tags: java, drupal, hostname

Is it possible to detect the hostname used in java (even through a cname)?

I am looking for something similar to this:
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/conf_path/6

In that code, drupal checks to see what domain name is accessing it in order to load the correct configuration (multi-site). If the domain doesn't match any configurations, it just goes to the default configuration.

Comment: Are you running in a servlet or what type of connection do you have ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [InetAddress.getLocalHost()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost()), followed by calling [getHostName()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName()) on the returned value, which does exactly this.

Be aware that not all machines will be able to resolve a network interface which can be used for the local hostname, and that multi-homed machines run into some additional complications too.  Thus if you're developing software that will need to work in a variety of situations, consider the edge cases properly as well as the happy path.

Answer (score 1):

Of course doing this causes a reverse DNS lookup for each getHostName() call.
It is a performance penalty on busy sites.
I would recommend doing getHostAddress() and later on looking up the host names.

Comment: this process is done at configuration time, probably *just once* when the webserver starts.  I don't see how the cost of doing a reverse DNS lookup could be a concern.